# Filter items based on jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using java object to extract data from my database and show the list of products in my application.

This is my code to list out the products.

**jQuery**

```
function getitemlist() {
    var url = serverURL() + "/getcatalogue.php";
    var JSONObject = {
        "subCategoryID": subCategoryID,
        "degreeID": degreeID
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _getitemlist(arr);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}

function _getitemlist(arr) {
    var i;
    $("#itemlist").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var t;
        t = "<a id='btnshowitem" + arr[i].itemID + "'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemImage+ "' class='image'> <br>"+ arr[i].itemName + "<br>"+ "Price: $" + arr[i].itemPrice + "</a>"
        $("#itemlist").append(t);
        $('#btnshowitem' + arr[i].itemID).bind("click", { id: arr[i].itemID}, function (event) {
            var data = event.data;
            showitemdetails(data.id);
        });
}
```

Is there anyway to filter the items? For example by price?

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` is nonsense - you are making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content of.

Comment: `var JSONObject = {` —That's a JavaScript object, not [a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @mthrsj — Why? The question is about filtering the response, not with server side code failing to understand the request. That will only break things.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. @bobby, if you want to filter, you could use the `Array.prototype.filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Array.prototype.filter`([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

```js
function _getitemlist(arr) {
  var i;
  var filter = "price";
  var value = 25;

  switch (filter) {
    case "price":
      arr = arr.filter(item => item.itemPrice > value);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  $("#itemlist").empty();

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var t;
    t = "<a id='btnshowitem" + arr[i].itemID + "'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemImage + "' class='image'> <br>" + arr[i].itemName + "<br>" + "Price: $" + arr[i].itemPrice + "</a>"
    $("#itemlist").append(t);

    $('#btnshowitem' + arr[i].itemID).bind("click", {
      id: arr[i].itemID
    }, function(event) {
      var data = event.data;
      showitemdetails(data.id);
    });
  }
}
```

In the example above, I've set a `Switch` to select which filter will be used, and a value. the `arr.filter` will return an array with all the items that the price is bigger than `value`.

I did the filter just before adding the items to the `dom`, then you can have multiple filters in a single function.